# HEROKU: What to do with my dump file (PGBACKUPS)

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm done with the pgbackups process.

First, I installed the pgbackups addon (HEROKU)
via command: heroku addons:add pgbackups

Second, I login using heroku auth:login command

Third, I capture the backup by running the command: heroku pgbackups:capture --app myapp

Fourth, I get the url of the backup by
heroku pgbackups:url b002

So I accessed the url that I saw after running the command: heroku pgbackups: url b002

in this format: https://s3.amazonaws.com/hkpgbackups/app2955630@heroku.com/b002.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=.......

something like that.

After that, I downloaded the file in .dump format

So now, I have the dump file and dont know what to do where to specifically use it...

Can somebody give me an advise to how to use the .dump file?

Please help me. I'm in trouble right now. I've to get a copy of our existing database from heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.dump` file should be a [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) file so you'd need to set up PostgreSQL somewhere and then use [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to load the `.dump` file into your local database.

Comment: I already have the dump file. But using pg_restore gives me a headache. It always says... pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "peekbox" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for u
ser "Rowell"

Comment: @XirukiTepe: So you got it all figured out while I was away, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again. Now I have another query. And it's about Git clone command. There's a YOUR KEY WITH FINGERPRINT ........ is not authorized to access.... blah blah error.

Comment: Will seek for an advise about that on the other question thread. Thanks. If you also know the answer about it, please do help me. ty

Comment: If you know the answer please leave it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499481/your-key-with-fingerprint-is-not-authorized-to-access-myapp-the-remote THANKS