# Your key with fingerprint .... is not authorized to access... myapp. The remote end hung up unexpectedly. HEROKU, GIT CLONE

Tags: git, heroku

I was planning to backup my source code from Heroku.

So I used the git clone command

to transfer the source code from Heroku to local machine.

I run the following commands

```
C:\Users\Rowell\myapp>git clone git@heroku.com:myapp.git c:\peekbox-recent
Cloning into 'c:\peekbox-recent'...

 **!  Your key with fingerprint eb:a9:b4:2f:5d:d8:21:27:1e:1e:34:60:de:eb:cf:eb is not authorized to access myapp.**

**fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
```

What could be the problem? Please help me.

Comment: Oops finally found the solution.

Comment: "Ignore this question" is against the spirit of Stack Overflow.  What would be a better approach would be to post what the solution you found was, so that others can benefit from it.  Sharing is caring :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue of anauthrized ssh key i.e. your ssh key is not present in your heroku account keys. Use
 heroku keys:add 
command to add your machines existing ssh key(or generate a new one if not exists) to heroku account .For more detailed steps please refer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys