# Key with fingerprint not authorized in Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

Trying, like so many others, to get my app to push to Heroku but keep getting this error

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: my@email.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Found existing public key: /Users/scotty/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/scotty/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Authentication successful.
$ git push heroku master

 !  Your key with fingerprint xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is not authorized to access todolist.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I completed all of the steps on the [Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) and I have tried most of the suggested fixes in these similar questions:

[Your key with fingerprint .... is not authorized to access... myapp. The remote end hung up unexpectedly. HEROKU, GIT CLONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499481/your-key-with-fingerprint-is-not-authorized-to-access-myapp-the-remote)

[Why is my key w/ fingerprint not authorized when I try to push latest changes to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049905/why-is-my-key-w-fingerprint-not-authorized-when-i-try-to-push-latest-changes-to)

[Cannot push to Heroku because key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint)

I've added a new key just for heroku, tried the ssh-add -D command to remove all keys, removed all keys from Heroku, and no matter what I try, I still get the same error.

I only have one Heroku account so the multiple account issue is not the problem. I now only have a single ssh key that I use for github on my macbook.

Does anyone have any suggestions not mentioned in the answers linked above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After you remove all keys with `ssh-add -D`, do you then manually add the Heroku key with `ssh-add <path to Heroku key>`?

Comment: I did that with the same result :(

Answer (score 7):

Generate a new key with:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku
```

Add it to your local ssh agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku
```

Make sure that the new key is showing up in the ssh-agent with:

```
 ssh-add -l
```

Remove unnecessary keys with the -d flag. (This will not delete the key, only remove it from the ssh-agent.)

```
ssh-add -d /Users/Niko/.ssh/id_rsa_hellonico
```

Add the ssh key to your acccount:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

Ready to push to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```