# SSH Fingerprint not authorized on Heroku after git restore

Tags: macos, git, heroku, ssh

I had to restore my master branch from github a couple weeks ago and since then I've been receiving an error that states "Your key with fingerprint... is not authorized to access my app."

I've looked at the previous answers to this problem and have tried deleting the old keypair, creating a new one and uploading it.

I used the following posts and still get the same error:

[Your key with fingerprint .... is not authorized to access... myapp. The remote end hung up unexpectedly. HEROKU, GIT CLONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499481/your-key-with-fingerprint-is-not-authorized-to-access-myapp-the-remote)

[Why is my key w/ fingerprint not authorized when I try to push latest changes to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049905/why-is-my-key-w-fingerprint-not-authorized-when-i-try-to-push-latest-changes-to)

[Cannot push to Heroku because key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786564/cannot-push-to-heroku-because-key-fingerprint)

When I run `ssh -Tv git@heroku.com` the terminal outputs the following:

> OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
> debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
> debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
> debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.154] port 22.
> debug1: Connection established.
> debug1: identity file /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
> debug1: identity file /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
> debug1: identity file /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
> debug1: identity file /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Twisted
> debug1: no match: Twisted
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
> debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
> debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
> debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
> debug1: Server host key: RSA [rsa key redacted]
> debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
> debug1: Found key in /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
> debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/anthonyfrancavilla/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku
> debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
> Authenticated to heroku.com ([50.19.85.154]:22).
> debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
> debug1: Entering interactive session.
> debug1: Sending environment.
> debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
> shell request failed on channel 0

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that the problem was in .git/config

The url under [remote "heroku"] was incorrect. I was able to reconnect once I corrected it.

Comment: and what's the correct one ?

[remote "heroku"] url = https  :  //git.heroku.com/<my_app>.git/

?
(i've put some spaces in url, so it's shown correctly)

Comment: @razor - i updated my remote from git@ to the format you suggested and everything started working.  I think you hit the nail on the head