# 'git push heroku master' is still asking for authentication

Tags: git, authentication, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have executed:

```
$ heroku login
```

But when I try to push, I'm still asked for authentication:

```
$ git push heroku master
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': <email>
Password for 'https://<email>@git.heroku.com':
```

Then I get a WARNING: Do not authenticate with username and password using Git.

I ran heroku login again and authenticated successfully but I still get the same failure.

I've checked the remote:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku https://git@heroku.com/appname.git (fetch)
heroku https://git@heroku.com/appname.git (push)
```

I've also generated a new public key, passed it to Heroku, and validated it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

I am on Windows 8, with Git 1.9.5.

Comment: How does your ssh config look? Have you added the host entry?

Comment: I've fixed the problem in the config file, as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721428/ssh-fingerprint-not-authorized-on-heroku-after-git-restore :/

Comment: Maybe my comment only can help few people, but I found that this error also occurs if your name of account(Windows account) consists of non-ASCII. I hope that this comment can help someone!

Comment: Get the heroku cmd, run `heroku login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon for the late reply, but I have fixed my problem two months ago. (Just haven't marked the question as answered. /noob)

[SSH Fingerprint not authorized on Heroku after git restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721428/ssh-fingerprint-not-authorized-on-heroku-after-git-restore)

Answer (score 216):

I got around this by logging in with the following :

username : *email used to register to heroku* (Also been able to leave this field *blank*)

password : *heroku auth token* (*API Key*)

where the auth token can be retrieved by `$ heroku auth:token` or via the Account Settings in Heroku

Comment: and by blank - you actually mean 'blank' in the username.

Comment: well, when I try "nothing" it says invalid entry. When I typed in "blank" it worked. This is on a windows system.

Comment: @NunoFurtado, however I've answered my problem with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721428/ssh-fingerprint-not-authorized-on-heroku-after-git-restore

Comment: Worked for me!
You can also get the auth key in https://dashboard.heroku.com/account -> API Key

Comment: although this made absolutely no sense to me, it did in fact work. magic.

Comment: Works like magic. I did heroku login and logged in, then checked out. When asked again for user name and password got the passord from website. Its called now API key

Comment: worked indeed, but I had to put my email as login... so here's another data point for you :)

Comment: For me email didn't work, blank username did. Thanks.

Comment: To generate long-term token I used this:
heroku authorizations:create

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem (git couldn't authenticate).
It happend that GIT wants to read auth data from %HOME%/_netrc file and on Windows you don't have this variable (only %USERPROFILE% and %HOMEDRIVE% + %HOMEPATH%)

i set HOME to %USERPROFILE%  (the place where heroku saved _netrc file) and GIT started working

Comment: Where do you get `%USERPROFILE%`? I have also tried to set `%HOME%` to an absolute path but all I get is untracked `_netrc` file. Does not work for me.

Comment: i'm setting `HOME=c:\users\razor` and it's a place of _netrc file `c:\users\razor\_netrc` Heroku created

Answer (score 18):

First find the `_netrc` file that is created by heroku. In windows it can be found in `C:\Users\User Name\_netrc`.

That file contains credentials for `git.heroku.com`

```
machine git.heroku.com
     login abcd123@gmail.com
     password xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Use that login and password when ask for authentication after `$ git push heroku master` command

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 18):

Username: the email you used for registering to Heroku
Password: the API key which Heroku provides you with, in your Account Settings on Heroku website

This worked for me

Comment: here [https://dashboard.heroku.com/account](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account). Roll down the screen and hit the reveal button.. Thanks @Sarah

Answer (score 15):

From the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#ssh-git-transport)

Enter the following commands:

```
# Enable SSH authentication
$ heroku create --ssh-git

# Redirect tall HTTPS calls to SSH
$ git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
```

Answer (score 8):

I have exactly the same problem. The reason in my case, I used accidentally window console instead of Git bash

Comment: Goes to show how there could be a lot of reasons behind one warning.

Comment: i dont see how this could cause the issue, actually I think I used windows cmd...

Comment: ffs, you're supposed to use the Git bash?

Comment: I get another error after I use Git bash. Maybe I'll stick to `cmd`

Comment: You should be able to use either. Or both. It just depends on whether or not you have your context set up with the proper heroku credentials.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is still struggling with this, this answer helped me a lot [Use Heroku API key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52790006/1150424).

First, as [@Raziza O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410260/raziza-o) mentioned in a comment, to get heroku API key

> https://dashboard.heroku.com/account. Roll down the screen and hit the reveal button.

Then, just run
`git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD:master`

Comment: this is the way

Answer (score 5):

> Renaming the `_netrc` file to `.netrc` on Windows 7 in the userdir worked for me.

..after trying all the steps in many other tutorials.

Run the 3rd command in cmd in your userdir or the whole combo:

```
setx HOME %USERPROFILE%
cd %HOME%
REN _netrc .netrc
```

Comment: In my case I did the login through a windows cmd prompt and wanted to use the credentials in Cygwin. Renaming the file `.netrc` in my home folder made git recognize it

Answer (score 3):

To generate a long term heroku token use:

```
heroku authorizations:create
```

Sample Output:

```
Creating OAuth Authorization... done
Client:      <none>
ID:          XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4c9c-85f2-554f0f0c14fa
Description: Long-lived user authorization
Scope:       global
Token:       XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4ad5-ac64-44bbc01c2d95
Updated at:  Wed Mar 04 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) (less than a minute ago)
```

---

Then use the following info for git:

```
username: blank (type the word blank)
pass: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4ad5-ac64-44bbc01c2d95
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it happened in 2 scenarios: when using in the first time or when it goes a long time without using git and it automatically logs out.

In both cases you just need to run `heroku login` and it will open the browser in order you can start a new session.

Answer (score 2):

Simply write: `$heroku login`
It will take you to the web login. Enter your credentials there, and you will be logged in via CLI as well.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because git and heroku aren't using the same `_netrc` file. This is something I'm trying to fix, but you can help me out by finding where your `_netrc` file should be and where the CLI is putting it.

The following will output potential sources of where the `_netrc` file could be:

```
> echo %HOME%
> echo %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
> echo %USERPROFILE%
```

You could try to add the `_netrc` file into one of them to find the one that matches. Let me know which has the `_netrc` file, and where you are able to put it and have git pick it up by not asking you for the username/password.

Also check your `.gitconfig` to see if there are any git credential helpers, that may be causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is trying to solve this on cygwin:
http://www.railszilla.com/git-push-heroku-master-authentication/start
rewriting to SSH transport did the trick for me:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably logged into `heroku` in two terminals, and if you try to run a command on first terminal, it will report such error, as new authentication was made in the second terminal.

Either login **again** with `heroku login` and run commands in that terminal, or run commands in that second window (if you have it still open).

Comment: This solution (`heroku login`) worked for me, though possibly for a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is old, I know.

However, none of the previous solutions worked for me.

My problem was that **"Windows Credentials"** (os: Windows 10) had another credential previously associated with Heroku (company account) and used this instead of the new one (my personal account).

I had to go to: **"Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager"** (from Control Panel), and modify all the credentials: https://git.heroku.com (and all those associated with "heroku" word) with the account current.

However, **the password I placed the Key API that is displayed in "Dashboard"** of the site and the command works: *git push heroku master.*

7 hours that life will not give me back. :/

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was open git bash instead of command prompt and type "git push heroku master". 
It worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the http address to `ssh://git@heroku/...`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows and get it sorted just using the PSW available on the on _netrc file it can be found in C:\Users\User Name_netrc.

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to log in using Heroku API Key (Account Settings -> API Key) as mentioned by `@andy mccullough`, however, logging in was needed every time.

```
git fetch
```

**resolved** the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `heroku login` per Git message.

> remote: ! WARNING:
> remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
> remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
> remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication

This should redirect you to the browser and bring up the Heroku Login page or in some cases actually just log you in using your credentials.