# Git Push Heroku Master HTTP Transport Authentication

Tags: git, http, authentication, heroku

I am having issues trying to push my app using git to heroku via HTTP. I have run:

```
$ heroku login
```

from the command prompt successfully, but when I try to push to heroku, I get prompted for a username and password again with the following message:

```
remote: ! WARNING
remote: ! Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: ! Run 'heroku login' to update your credentials, then try the git command.
```

This is similar to what was described in [git push heroku master still asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810419/git-push-heroku-master-is-still-asking-for-authentication), but the url in my .git/.config files appears match what is on the dashboard.

I verified that the api key matches what is on the heroku dashboard using:

```
$ heroku auth:token
```

I have also tried to regenerate the API key and got the same result. Has anyone resolved this issue with Heroku using the HTTP Git transport?