# Heroku : Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': git

Tags: windows, git, heroku

[image]

I'm trying to check a git remote on heroku:

```
$ heroku auth:logout
Local credentials cleared.

$ heroku auth:login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: ***@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.

$ git remote
heroku
origin

$ git remote show heroku
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com':
Password for 'https://git.heroku.com':
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/***-1909.git/'
```

This error is referenced in the heroku docs, in the screenshot above at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git , but I'm not sure what to do next to fix this.

Comment: shouldn't you use a key instead of a password?

Comment: When you say you've already logged out and logged back in, are you talking about Heroku's website or the `heroku` command line tool?

Comment: The command line tool

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28331676/1504372 it's based on the last paragraph from the docs you posted.

Answer (score 36):

This is what worked for me.

`$ heroku auth:token`

Use the result as the password when prompted.

Comment: Agreed @rkyr This is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: This works - is there any way to save the credentials?

Answer (score 32):

As the warning says, you just need to do:

`heroku login`

And it will open your browser for logging in, enter details as per your authentication and you will be good to roll in.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication for more details

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me - still prompted. the 'auth:token' approach worked tho

Comment: This worked for me; it is also the approach suggested by the Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started

Comment: This worked for me, the first answer didn't

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue `no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)` by it by pushing the updates to heroku and when they asked for the user name I added my email and the password it's in this link https://dashboard.heroku.com/account in API KEYS

Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': your email

Password for 'https://email@git.heroku.com': API KEYS

Answer (score 1):

Run this

1. heroku login
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "..."
4. git push heroku main

This is going to work

Answer (score 0):

After logged with: `heroku login`
Some access for example on cloning an existing project in your account, is not
allowed using git native even stay you logged in, and only using git from heroku, such as:

```
heroku git:[command]
```

an example clonning a repository:

```
heroku git:clone -a [app_name]
```

Otherwise, sometimes, after logged with `heroku login`, you can check your remote git with: `git remote -v`

Other way, is you use `heroku auth:token` and use their output as password, of course, run it after logged.