# Push Changes to Git not Functioning

Tags: windows, git, github, heroku

Every time I want to commit the command "git push heroku master" I am asked in the PowerShell to enter the credentials. When I enter heroku credentials (which is connected to git by default) I get the error message.

But, when I type the credetials contained in the netrc file in my home directory, then the thing functions. The password is however hashed in my opinion. How can I avoid entering credentials every time I want to push changes to git?

UPDATE:

```
PS C:\Users\Dragan\heroku_workspace\python-getting-started> git push heroku master
github --credentials get: github: command not found
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': my-email@hotmail.com
Password for 'https://my-email@hotmail.com@git.heroku.com':
github --credentials erase: github: command not found
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !       See documentation for details: Https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git#authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-river-71834.git/'
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get? You should only have to do `heroku login` one time.

Comment: @Harrison the comand heroku login functions with my heroku credentials. However the comand git pushe heroku master does not when I enter the same credentials as before. It only functions when I enter the hashed password I found in the netrc file, and in addition to that I have to do it every time I want to do git push... the error message is in the description of the issue in my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake is cloning using the default (HTTPS) instead of SSH. You can correct this by going to your repository, clicking the ssh button left to the URL field and updating the URL of your origin remote like this:
`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git`

or if your repository already then click green button `CLONE OR DOWNLOAD` and select use `SSH`

## Enable SSH authentication

`$ heroku create --ssh-git`

## Redirect tall HTTPS calls to SSH `( If you want to always use SSH Git with Heroku on a particular machine)`

`$ git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/`

## To generate a public key:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`  Press enter at the first prompt to use the default file location. Next, type a secure passphrase for the key.

Comment: can you be more specific? where exactly do  i need to switch from https to ssh?

Comment: 1. if you go to github WEBSITE and `Login`                                                 2. go to your repository main page.                                                                 3. then on the `RIGHT-SIDE` your going to see a `GREEN BUTTON` that says `CLONE OR DOWNLOAD` click it

Comment: I have found where I can swith from https to ssl, however, the git repository in the stated case is created by heroku automatically and I do not know where to find that one. this is the link: https://git.heroku.com/mysterious-river-71834.git

Comment: you need to `1 create ssh-git` then `2 tell heroku to use ssh instead of  hhtp in your computer` and you may need to `3 Create a key ` here is the [link to keys] (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v1.9.3 or later [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads), you can do the following

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Please note that this mechanism stores your username/password in Windows Credential Store.

In relatively newer versions, [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) is bundled with [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and enabled by default, you might have to override `credential.helper` configuration for Heroku. GCM seems designed for VSTS and GitHub and I am not how it will behave with other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

1. Run `heroku login` using the windows command prompt `cmd.exe`. This will drop your API key into your `_netrc` at which point you can open up cygwin or git bash and do whatever you need to
2. From `.gitconfig` remove the `helper = manager` line so that it is no longer registered as a credential helper and stops it from showing up.

   (in `C:\Users\username\.gitconfig` )
3. Rename _netrc file to .netrc on Windows 7 in the user dir:

   `cd %home%`

   `REN _netrc .netrc`

see:

['git push heroku master' is still asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810419/git-push-heroku-master-is-still-asking-for-authentication)

https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84#issuecomment-170689175