# Invalid email for Heroku login using Git Bash?

Tags: heroku, authentication, git-bash

I was able to use heroku login with my windows power shell successfully. However, when running the latest version of Git Bash and running the same heroku login command, after it asks for my email and I enter it I get the following message: 
!Login is currently incompatible with git bash/Cygwin/MinGW

Any ideas on how to fix this so I can access Heroku on my Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

[A fix is discussed as a github issue here](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84). You may not have the Path properly set. Some indicate success with logging in via cmd first. If logging via windows cmd doesn't work, exit git bash, login on cmd then restart git bash.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I posted in reply to [Push Changes to Git not Functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936593/push-changes-to-git-not-functioning) worked for me:

1. Run `heroku login` using the windows command prompt `cmd.exe`. This will drop your API key into your `_netrc` at which point you can open up cygwin or git bash and do whatever you need to
2. From `.gitconfig` remove the `helper = manager` line so that it is no longer registered as a credential helper and stops it from showing up.

   (in `C:\Users\username\.gitconfig` )
3. Rename _netrc file to .netrc on Windows 7 in the user dir:

   `cd %home%`

   `REN _netrc .netrc`

see:

['git push heroku master' is still asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810419/git-push-heroku-master-is-still-asking-for-authentication)

https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/84#issuecomment-170689175