# Login to Heroku with GitLab CI.yml

Tags: heroku, gitlab

I've been trying to deploy my GitLab application to Heroku, but unfortunatelt I keep getting this error when I try to run `heroku login -i`

```
Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
```

I've looked at solutions from the web for this, but none seem to help. Am I going about this wrong?

Here's my YML file

```
before_script:
  - echo "Running job..."

build_job_1:
  script:
    - heroku login -i
    - blank
    - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX # Account token
    - git remote add heroku https://heroku:XXXXX@git.heroku.com/redditchatbot.git 
    - git push heroku HEAD:master
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT: I've included the full log below**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.9.0-rc2 (227934c0)
  on docker-auto-scale 0277ea0f
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:e86557c9a8ab97ec7e9ba705f3e3411428b50d19d38643a0f52cb49faf735d3d for ruby:2.5 ...
Running on runner-0277ea0f-project-11711672-concurrent-0 via runner-0277ea0f-srm-1554580242-7d379f26...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/WillWam/reddump/.git/
Fetching changes...
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/WillWam/reddump
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out f2d6762d as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Running job..."
Running job...
$ git remote add heroku https://heroku:XXXXX@git.heroku.com/redditchatbot.git
$ git push heroku HEAD:master
remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://heroku:XXXX@git.heroku.com/redditchatbot.git/'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do not authenticate with username and password using git

That means: don't use heroku:XXXXX in your URL: the heroku login should cache your credentials, which implies you don't need said credentials in the URL.

If the issue persists, then check one of the solutions to "['`git push heroku master`' is still asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27810419/6309)"